# how to insert all records of excel sheet into sql data base using wso2 dss 6.4.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am new to wso2 6.4.0. I have to insert excel data to sql so i choose wso2 dss. Using dss records fetching correctly and inserting too but inserting only one record(top one only) remain records getting skipped. I used nested query option also to retrieve as well as insertion.

```
<query id="readExcelData" useConfig="excelConfig">  
<excel>
<workbookname>sheet1</workbookname>
<hasheader>true</hasheader>
<startingrow>2</startingrow>
<maxrowcount>-1</maxrowcount>
<headerrow>1</headerrow>
</excel>
<result element="Products" rowName="Product">           
<element column="ID" name="ID" xsdType="xs:string"/>
<element column="Model" name="Model" xsdType="xs:string"/>
<element column="Classification" name="Classification" xsdType="xs:string"/>
<call-query href="insertIntoSql" requiredRoles="">      
<with-param name="ID" query-param="ID" />
<with-param name="Model" query-param="Model" />
<with-param name="Classification" query-param="Classification" />
</call-query>
</result>    
</query>
<operation name="excelFileProcessing" returnRequestStatus="true">
<call-query href="readExcelData"/>          
</operation>
<query id="insertIntoSql" useConfig="sqlConfig">                                    
<sql>insert into dbo.myProductList(ID,Model,Classification) values(:ID,:Model,:Classification)</sql>                                    
<param name="ID" sqlType="STRING" />                                    
<param name="Model" sqlType="STRING" />                                    
<param name="Classification" sqlType="STRING" />                  
</query>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you retrieve records from Excel sheet you are getting sets of records. Therefore you have to write a synapse config to insert each record. For that, you have iterate over the payload of excel sheet's data (for each record) and insert. You can use [iterate mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Iterate+Mediator). For an example you can implement something similar to [this](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/iterate-and-aggregate-mediators-with-call-mediator-in-wso2-esb).

You can follow,

1. In the proxy service/ API call the dataservice to get excel sheet's
   data.
2. Iterate over the result set.
3. In each iteration, create the
   payload to insert data to DB and call the dataservice to invoke the
   insert data query.
4. Invoke the proxy service / API.

Comment: Hi, thanks first of all. All records from the excel sheet inserting into db properly. I have changed the sql connector afterwards it works finely. I used "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" this one instead of "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"